# Asynchronous call using Promise all

Tags: node.js

I have a doubt when making multiple requests using Promise.all. Although it works I'm wondering if it is asynchronous (multiple requests, the slowest request will make all others wait for return) and if there is a better way of doing it

Here is my code

```
//Passing an array with length of 1000 with numbers inside
//produtosIdArray: Array(1000) [1388, 72533, 87988, …]

var produtoObj = {};
var resultRobo = {};

await Promise.all(
produtosIdArray.map(async produtoId => {
  try {
    // api request
    produtoObj = await crawlerApi.getProdutosById(produtoId);
    resultRobo[produtoId] = {};

    if ((produtoObj.message != undefined && produtoObj.message != "Product not found") || produtoObj.searches.length > 0 ) {
      produtoObj.searches.forEach(element => {
        let lojaId = element.store["_id"];
        resultRobo[produtoId][lojaId] = {
          nomeLoja:
            element.store.name == ""
              ? element.store.domain
              : element.store.name,
          preco: substituiPonto(parseFloat(element.price).toFixed(2)),
          url: element.url.url,
          status: element.status,
          tempoFila: element.row.time
          //data: diferencaEmHoras(new Date(element.row.updatedAt), new Date())
        };

      });
    }
  }catch(err) {
    resultRobo[produtoId] = {};
  }
})
);
```

My idea is to store it on a result object (resultRobo) with all data returned from the 1000 calls.

Comment: You probably shouldn't spin up 1000 concurrent HTTP requests, but in addition, your code should probably be `return crawlerApi.getProdutosById(id);` instead of assigning it to an implicit global that's never referenced. If you want the requests to be processed as they come in, there's no need to use `Promise.all()`. That just ensures you get an array of results back in the order that they were made, whereas if you want to handle them as they are processed, you may not get results in the same order.

Comment: I'll add some more code to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use rxjs library and solve this in reactive.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin'; 
forkJoinTest() {
  const productRequests = prodIdArray.map(id => crawlerApi.getProdutosById(id));
  const requests = forkJoin(productRequests);
  requests.subscribe(
    data => console.log(data), //process item or push it to array
    err => console.log(err) 
  );
}
```

Comment: how would that be in node.js?